# extracting a vector from a Repa Array

Tags: haskell, image-processing, repa

hello everyone I have this function in haskell that let me extract a Repa array from bitmap grayScale

```
readImageFromBMPa
        :: FilePath
        -> IO (Either Error (Array U DIM2 ( Word8)))

{-# NOINLINE readImageFromBMPa #-}
readImageFromBMPa filePath
 = do   ebmp    <- readBMP filePath

        case ebmp of
         Left err       -> return $ Left err
         Right bmp      
          -> do arr    <- readImageFromBMPPrime  bmp
                return  $ Right arr
```

I searched on way to extract a vector from this function output I
I found toUnboxed Function  like this

```
let a =  Prelude.map (\(v) -> toUnboxed (readImageFromBMPa v))(fst ns)
```

I get the following error
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Array U sh0 e’
with actual type ‘IO (Either Error (Array U DIM2)

is there a way I can do the conversion thanks

Comment: This question doesn't really have anything to do with Repa or vectors, but with the fact that you can't apply a function `A -> B` to a value of type `IO A` (let alone `IO (Either Error A)`). There are lots of existing questions dealing with that subject.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, type passed to `toUnboxed` is wrong. Type `Array U DIM2` you want is wrapped by `IO a` monad and `Either a b` monad. It needs to peel off them in order to deal with the content. This sample is same problem.

```hs
main = do
    str <- getLine  :: IO String
    putStrLn str -- putStrLn :: String -> IO ()
```